# Javascript: what's colon operator in variable name?

Tags: javascript, operator-keyword

i have code like this:

```
var db: name = dbFunction(true);

dbFunction returning Object.
```

I have question, what doing this colon operator in variable name?

Comment: It is causing a syntax error to be thrown.

Comment: I have code created by IBM and i dont think it's syntax error

Comment: I've inherited some working code with something similar `const store: Object = configureStore()`, and am similarly confused.

Answer (score 5):

It's a high tech operator that guarantees a syntax error when used like that.

In it's normal use, you might see it used in object literal syntax to denote key:value pairs;

```
var object = {
    "name": "value",
    "name2": "value2"
}
```

It can also be used to define a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) (less common).

```
loop1:  
for (var i=0;i<10; i++) {
   for (var j=0;j<10;j++) {
      break loop1; // breaks out the outer loop
   }  
}
```

And it's part of the ternary operator;

```
var something = conditional ? valueIfTrue : valueIfFalse;
```

Comment: Ha ha ha.. Thats the most sophisticated way of mocking a person !!

Answer (score 3):

The colon has several uses in JavaScript.

1. It's used to separate keys from values in the JSON notation.

```
var db = {
    name: dbFunction(name)
};
```

2. It's the ternary operator:

`var db = (1 == 1 ? true : false);`

3. Labels aka `GOTO`. Stay away from them.

Answer (score 0):

It is also used in switch cases:

```
switch(product) {
    case "apple":
        return "Yum";
        break;
    case "orange":
        return "juicy!";
        break;
    case "milk":
        return "cold!";
        break;
}
```