# colon in variable declaration

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm going through some Unity tutorials and came across this line of code in one of the sample scripts. I'm familiar with javascript but I have never seen the colon used when declaring a variable except for object literals.

`var controller : CharacterController = GetComponent(CharacterController);`

What is the colon doing in this line.

at the end of the script there is this other line of code that might be relevant

`@script RequireComponent(CharacterController)`

Here is the full sample code from unity:

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/CharacterController.SimpleMove.html

--

I have searched SO for duplicates but the only one i found was this one:

[Javascript: what's colon operator in variable name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211204/javascript-whats-colon-operator-in-variable-name)

and the guy was laughed out of the site

Comment: Are you sure that code is JavaScript?  Look again, it's UnityScript.  Please see [this page](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/UnityScript_versus_JavaScript) for a great summary of the differences between the two languages

Comment: @Lex, It's not really pure JavaScript. Your example must have an "compiler" to compile the JS to the style. Actually, ActionScript use this style declaration.

Comment: Life makes sense again. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unity's JavaScript isn't actually JavaScript but a heavily modified variant of ECMAScript. It's also called UnityScript, which is a more accurate name.

The colon in variable declaration is used **in Unity** for specifying the type of the variable. In this case `controller` is of type `CharacterController` which in turn is a class. The syntax is invalid in "actual" JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Everywhere I looked it was simply referred to as JavaScript.