# UnityScript error in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, unityscript

[image]

So I´ve been working with unity this days for school and I have the coding for a spaceship to move only in certain space with the variables hori and vert like this:

```
var vert: float = 0
```

and

```
var hori: float = 0
```

but the program tells me its a semicolon instead of the colon i dont know why and also i use `&&` and it says syntax error... someone please help me

Comment: could you include the code chunk with everything related and the specific error?

Comment: i will post an image

Comment: didnt let me post the image but the link

Comment: why are you using `float`, when it looks like `int` should do

Comment: I am using a tutuorial and it said to use float... I will try with int!

Comment: @amvd The following are for your future reference. 1) **[How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186/293688)**? and 2) What is a **[Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [colon in variable declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18940578/colon-in-variable-declaration)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the `&&` is improper parenthesis. You have:

```
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow)) && vert < 3) {
```

and I think it should be something like:

```
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) && vert < 3) {
```

Comment: know something about the ´:´ ?

Comment: or change `0` to `0.0f`

Comment: I changed it but it still says its ; instead of :

Comment: it doesnt show anymore problems so I think it does :)